# Can a moderator please symlink x11 to xorg?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

[x11](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/x11) has a number in it, so the system assumes it's a version number and won't let me submit it as a proposed synonym.

Can someone make it a synonym of [xorg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/xorg)?

Answer (score 7):

Its done. x11 is now a sym of xorg.